# Check if a particular criteria is empty with MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I want to take a look at whether Table B has any values in the column child_id, which are also associated with loc_id from Table A.

I have already pulled loc_id's value, and there is a loc_id in Table B that has a relationship with Table A's.

How do I use loc_id to determine whether or not there is a loc_id of the same value in Table B?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Given loc_id X in table A, do you want to find records with loc_id X in table B? child_id X in B?

Comment: Well, first I want to see if there ARE any records with loc_id X in Table B, and then second I will want to be able to pull child_id X based on them. But this initially is just for a test to see if a given loc_id should get a button.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. Could you show the table structure and some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do here, but if you want to see if there's a non empty/non null entry for loc_id in Table B, then you would go:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB
WHERE loc_id IS NULL;
```

If you want to see which loc_ids in table a don't have a corresponding entry in table b, then this should suffice:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.loc_id = tableB.loc_id
WHERE tableB.loc_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
select * from tableb
where child_id in (select loc_id from tablea);
```

To find those that *don't* match:

```
select * from tableb
where child_id not in (select loc_id from tablea);
```